# Is there a faster way to build a list of lists?

Tags: python

I have code which is matching features within regions. The first thing it does it matches features from one region to an entire database of region features.

So I have a mapping from query feature index (qfx) into database feature index (ax).
A database feature index has associated with it a region id (rid), region feature index (fx), feature score (fs), and feature rank (fk). 
There is also a flag marking each of those mappings as valid or invalid.

The problem is that I want to go from this mapping of query_feature_index-to-database_feature_index (qfx2_ax) into a mapping from region_index-to-feature_match (rid2_fm, rid2_fs, and rid2_fk)

I have the following code which does this (cleaned up just a little bit for clarity). On the left hand size is the rough percentage of time each step takes. The bulk of the time seems to be eaten up by appending to the lists in the default dictionaries.

It seems to me as if there is no better way to do this, but maybe someone out there knows something I don't. Maybe there is a numpy routine I'm unaware of?

```
  0.0      for qrid in qrid2_nns.iterkeys():
  0.0          (qfx2_ax, _) = qrid2_nns[qrid]
  0.0          (qfx2_fs, qfx2_valid) = qrid2_nnfilt[qrid]
  0.0          nQKpts = len(qfx2_ax)
               # Build feature matches
  0.0          qfx2_nnax = qfx2_ax[:, 0:K]
  0.4          qfx2_rid  = ax2_rid[qfx2_nnax]
  0.5          qfx2_fx   = ax2_fx[qfx2_nnax]
  0.2          qfx2_qfx = np.tile(np.arange(nQKpts), (K, 1)).T
  0.1          qfx2_k   = np.tile(np.arange(K), (nQKpts, 1))
               # Pack valid feature matches into an interator
  0.4          valid_lists = [qfx2_[qfx2_valid] for qfx2_ in (qfx2_qfx, qfx2_rid, qfx2_fx, qfx2_fs, qfx2_k,)]
  0.0          match_iter = izip(*valid_lists)
  0.0          rid2_fm = defaultdict(list)
  0.0          rid2_fs = defaultdict(list)
  0.0          rid2_fk = defaultdict(list)
               # This creates the mapping I want. Can it go faster?
 19.3          for qfx, rid, fx, fs, fk in match_iter:
 17.2              rid2_fm[rid].append((qfx, fx)) 
 17.0              rid2_fs[rid].append(fs)
 16.2              rid2_fk[rid].append(fk)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: however the answer is almost definately yes ...